# Assigning Records SQL

Tags: sql, ssis

I have four tables in my database. What I want to achieve is to - based on the Organization assigned to Users - be able to assign orders to right users, also - to be able to weight (by counting cases for each user) to avoid assigning too many orders to same user.

I totally have no idea where to start with SQL for that... any thoughts ? Thanks !

```
Orders
+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+
| OrderNumber  | DateReceived | Organization | UserAssign |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+
| ON2197802293 | 03.01.2014   |            6 | null       |
| ON2080463210 | 26.08.2014   |            2 | null       |
| ON8889958731 | 21.12.2013   |            7 | null       |
| ON6534106324 | 01.05.2014   |            7 | null       |
| ON5649138524 | 15.09.2014   |            6 | null       |
| ON3917853693 | 17.03.2014   |            8 | null       |
| ON5274601699 | 13.02.2014   |            2 | null       |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+------------+

Users
 +----+--------------+------------+
 | ID |   UserName   | CasesCount |
 +----+--------------+------------+
 |  1 | John Doe     | null       |
 |  2 | Adam Smith   | null       |
 |  3 | David Liu    | null       |
 |  4 | Deborah Poe  | null       |
 |  5 | Dan Bacon    | null       |
 |  6 | Dragan Tomic | null       |
 +----+--------------+------------+

+--------------+--------------+  +-----------+-------+
| Organization |              |  | UsersOrgs |       |
+--------------+--------------+  +-----------+-------+
| ID           | Organization |  | UserID    | OrgID |
| 1            | R120         |  | 1         | R120  |
| 2            | P234         |  | 1         | P234  |
| 3            | X097         |  | 2         | D982  |
| 4            | D982         |  | 3         | R120  |
| 5            | F938         |  | 3         | P234  |
| 6            | B726         |  | 3         | X097  |
| 7            | E311         |  | 3         | D982  |
| 8            | L221         |  | 4         | R120  |
| 9            | K991         |  | 4         | P234  |
| 10           | M982         |  | 5         | R120  |
| 11           | W123         |  | 5         | P234  |
+--------------+--------------+  | 5         | L221  |
                                 | 6         | R120  |
                                 | 6         | P234  |
                                 | 6         | X097  |
                                 +-----------+-------+
```

Comment: write a function to determine which user has the least amount of orders for an organization passing in organization return userID.  If you have multiple users having the same count, order by random so it picks one at random and return that user.  now conditions apply: is the user active, how do you determine an order is still in progress vs closed etc. call the function when inserting a new order to assign to that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PSEUDO CODE:

```
Create Function UserAssignment(@OrgID)
declare returnvalue as same type as usersID
set returnvalue = -1
    Select top 1 count(*), userAssign  into returnValue from orders
    where organization = @orgID
    order by count desc, random()
   --if return value is -1 then no users assigned to ORG having order.
   userassignment = retvalue
end function
```

---Now update all existing orders...
Update Orders set userAssign = UserAssignment(Organization) where userAssign is null;

-- and on future insert statemetns

```
insert into orders (Fields...,UserAssign) values (fields..., UserAssignment(@Organization)
```

OR instead of handling on insert

--in a trigger call the fucntion to update the value

--modify table structure to set a default value based on a call to the function

These last 2 are useful if you anticipate orders coming in though non-standard ways.

--Write a scheduled job that updates blank orders

```
Update Orders set userAssign = UserAssignment(Organization) where userAssign is null;
```

Comment: Thanks for that - Exactly - I want to create a scheduled job that will perform the assignment

Comment: This high level example led me to the resolution - Thank You very much :)